# Can't launch Spring TaskScheduler from Spring Batch Admin app

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have a spring batch admin project (1.3.0.RC1) and I'm trying to enable a TaskScheduler to run a job using a cron expression.

I have one project for spring batch admin and I have another project with my batch job. I can execute the job just fine through the admin console manually (meaning it loads fine and works). The job never executes on the cron schedule though.

If I configure a java class with a main method and run it as a java application using the same job xml file, the job will run on the cron schedule (In other words, run the job outside of the Spring batch admin console). This should also verify that the xml configuration is okay.

this works:
project2 app.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String springConfig = "META-INF/spring/batch/jobs/scheduleTest.xml";
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);
}
```

project2 META-INF/spring/jobs/scheduleTest.xml

```
    <job id="test-job"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="testJob">
            <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" ref="testOutput"/>
        </step>
    </job>


    <bean id="testOutput" class="com.default.test.testOutput" />


    <task:scheduled-tasks>
        <task:scheduled ref="runIt" method="run" cron="30 * * * * ?" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>

    <bean id="runIt" class="com.default.scheduler.RunScheduler">
        <property name="job" ref="test-job" />
        <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher"/>
        <property name="runCron" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

The job runs every 30 seconds and prints some test output to the console.

Doesn't work:
When I run the Spring Batch Admin console, project2 gets packaged with project1, the job.xml file becomes part of the classpath, and the job is registered in the console and is launchable. I can run it from the console and it works fine, but it doesn't run at the scheduled time automatically. It also doesn't start running on the scheduled time after I manually execute it.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Or if anyone knows of an example of using the Spring TaskScheduler (not quartz) in SBA, that would also be helpful. Thanks in advance. My guess is that cron expression is getting stored into an application context that no longer exists or isn't known to the SBA console.

Comment: How will SBA know that it has two call your App.java?

Comment: on project 2, Try to add your `scheduleTest.xml` under `META-INF/spring/batch/jobs` (don't forget the `batch` folder)

Comment: @OussamaZoghlami yes, good catch. I misspelled it in the description but it is in fact under `META-INF/spring/batch/jobs`

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem in SBA 1.3.0.RELEASE. It works with main method that manually loads context, but when in SBA it doesn't run TaskScheduler.

For debugging purpose, I have an ApplicationListener. In onApplicationEvent method, I manually create and run my own TaskScheduler.

META-INF/spring/batch/jobs/sba-configuration.xml

```
<job id="test-job"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="testJob">
        <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" ref="testOutput"/>
    </step>
</job>

<bean id="testOutput" class="com.default.test.testOutput" />


<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="runIt" method="run" cron="30 * * * * ?" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<bean id="runIt" class="com.default.scheduler.RunScheduler">
    <property name="job" ref="test-job" />
    <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher"/>
    <property name="runCron" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="appContextListener" class="com.qmn.AppContextListener" />
<bean id="myJobRunner" class="com.qmn.MyJobRunner"/>
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10" />
```

com.qmn.AppContextListener

```
public class AppContextListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac; //this context doesn't contain beans which are in sba-configuration.xml

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler; //in sba-configuration.xml but doesn't have in wac. Spring still injects success.

    @Autowired
    private MyJobRunner myJobRunner; //in sba-configuration.xml but doesn't have in wac

    @Autowired
    private Job job; //in sba-configuration.xml but doesn't have in wac

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher; // default jobLauncher of SBA

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
        XmlWebApplicationContext context = contextRefreshedEvent.getSource() instanceof XmlWebApplicationContext ?
                (XmlWebApplicationContext) contextRefreshedEvent.getSource() : null;

        if(context != null && context.getNamespace().contains("Batch Servlet")) { // only work with my spring batch admin servlet
            myJobRunner.setJob(job);
            myJobRunner.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
            CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger("*/5 * * * * *");
            ScheduledFuture<?> scedulefuture = scheduler.schedule(myJobRunner, trigger);
        }
    }

}
```

The code works well, run job every 5s. So I guess SBA ate TaskScheduler which is defined in xml config. Is this a bug of Spring Batch Admin?